# How to turn this VB.net declaration into the equivalent for VB6 style and what's the process?

Tags: vb.net

```
<DllImport("ieframe.dll", EntryPoint:="IEGetProtectedModeCookie")> _
Public Function IEGetProtectedModeCookie( _
    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpszURL As String, _
    <[In](), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal lpszCookieName As String, _
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal pszCookieData As StringBuilder, _
    ByRef pcchCookieData As UInteger, _
    ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
End Function
```

Those marshalas thingy look ugly

For comparison, typical vb6 style is:

```
Declare Function InternetGetCookieEx Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetGetCookieExA" (ByVal pchURL As String, ByVal pchCookieName As String, ByVal pchCookieData As String, ByRef pcchCookieData As System.UInt32, ByVal dwFlags As System.UInt32, ByVal lpReserved As Integer) As Boolean
```

No marshal this no marshal that no [in] thingy. How do I turn that?

Is this the right way?

```
Declare Function IEGetProtectedModeCookie Lib "ieframe.dll" (ByVal lpszURL As String, ByVal lpszCookieName As String, ByVal pszCookieData As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByRef pcchCookieData As UInteger, ByVal dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
```

Comment: Does it work? If Yes, then it is. If No, please update your question and add more information (such as when it fails).

Comment: No it doesn't. IEGetProtectedModeCookie need Charset specified. I got error Invalid argument or something.